# serializing a large struct without "save" methods

Tags: c++, serialization

I have a large configuration struct which consists of sub struct, int, char, long and strings. the sub structs are also built from the same elements.

this configuration struct needs to be serialized and sent between nodes on a cluster.

I was looking for a way to serialize this without making "save" methods in each struct like cereal and boost libraries want. the code is shared among a few programmers and the struct is very big. I am afraid that someone will update the struct or one of its substructs and forget to update the "save method accordingly

ideas?

** in cpp

Comment: Is a binary representation an option?

Comment: I am afraid that someone will update the struct or one of its substructs and forget to update the "save method accordingly   -   This is what tests are for.   If your configuration can be compared with the == nicely, then you can serialise, de-serialise and then compare & assert the same.

Comment: @StephanLechner binary representation is an option, I don't care how it is serialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can be sure that all the nodes in the cluster have the same architecture and execute the same compiled code, you could actually transfer the data in binary mode, i.e. as a "raw memory dump" of an object. The same architecture / same compiled code is required, since different architectures and/or different compilers could lead to different sizes of the datatypes used and also to different "padding". Then, the memory layout used by the sender and the receiver could be different, leading to a mess of the data.

Note further that your "struct" (or class) must be a POD type, i.e. no virtual constructors/destructors, no virtual member functions such that you can initialise it with a "memory dump".

If you are aware of these restrictions, see the following code, which "simulates" a transfer by writing and reading to a file in binary mode. Adapt this code to actually transfer the code using a channel of your choice, e.g. sockets.

Hope it helps.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct myStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
    char name[10];
    double z;

    void printOnConsole() {
        cout << "x:" << x << ";y:" << y << ";name:"<< name << ";z:" << z << endl;
    }
    void writeBinary(ofstream &out) {
        out.write((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
    }
    bool readBinary(ifstream &in) {
        in.read((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
        return in.gcount() == sizeof(*this);
    }
};


int main()
{
    myStruct myStructObjs[] = {
        { 10, 20, "Herbert", 3.5 },
        { 30, 40, "Anton", 4.6 }
    };
    cout << "Objects to be transferred:" << endl;
    myStructObjs[0].printOnConsole();
    myStructObjs[1].printOnConsole();

    cout << "Simulating transfer:" << endl;
    ofstream send("data.bin", ios_base::binary | ios_base::out);
    if (send) {
        myStructObjs[0].writeBinary(send);
        myStructObjs[1].writeBinary(send);
        send.close();
        cout << "Two objects transferred." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error 'sending' data." << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    cout << "Simulating receive:" << endl;
    ifstream receive("data.bin", ios_base::binary);
    if (receive) {
        myStruct receivedObj;
        int n = 0;
        while (receivedObj.readBinary(receive)) {
            receivedObj.printOnConsole();
            n++;
        }
        cout << n << " objects received." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error 'receiving' data." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my struct is not POD since it has strings, but after reading around it seems best to make them char[] and do as you suggest. I should note for others tho that if they use cpp 14 they can use boost hana to traverse the struct and serialize easily

Answer (score 0):

Boost offers a non-intrusive way to serialize, [see here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html) under "non intrusive version"

Comment: Given that the OP has already stated they're aware of boost, I don't think this answer adds much.

Comment: His question implies that he thinks he has to put a save method into the class using boost. That's not the case using the non intrusive version.

Comment: @mattideluxe the problem is not weather to put the save inside  or not. the problem is that a developer might accidentally forget to enter a new value in both places

Comment: @Epic & UKMonkey: You are absolutely right... I guess I skipped the last part of the question.. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

There's no reflection in C++. QT and Unreal Engine are using their own compile steps to create code reflection for that purpose. Also you can look into [cpp3k](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0590r0.pdf) which is a clang extension.

I can suggest you a way to ensure that structures modification without proper update in save function would be noticeable:

```
struct myData {
int32_t a;
uint8_t b;
};

void save(const myData& data) {
    save(data.a);
    save(data.b);
    assert(sizeof(myData) == 5); // When adding new elements to myData make sure to update this function
}
```

P.S. Make sure alignment doesn't mess with your size.

---

UPD.

This library might help you [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).
Also these two articles are pretty interesting [An Introduction to Reflection in C++](http://jackieokay.com/2017/04/13/reflection1.html), [Fun with Reflection in C++](http://jackieokay.com/2017/05/06/reflection2.html)

UPD.2

You might want to look at [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or similar library.

Comment: I came across boost hana in your links. which seems to allow traversing the struct members. I can't use it since it needs cpp 14 but it might be useful for someone

Answer (score 0):

> am afraid that someone will update the struct or one of its substructs and forget to update the "save method accordingly

how about putting a

```
McCfgStruct::serialize(...) {
  std::static_assert(sizeof(MyCfgStruct) == 32);
}
```

(or equivalent) This way, if someone adds a new variable into the struct and doesn't update the serialize method's expected size you'l get a compiler error.